# Help passing reference to class subroutine in Perl

Tags: perl, pass-by-reference, perl-module

I am trying to pass a routine to another subroutine within a Perl module. But when I pass the sub reference the passed in ref no longer has the object data. Maybe its not possible to do it this way. The line I have a question about is the "unless" lines below:

```
sub get_flag_end {
   my $self = shift;
   return ( -e "$self->{file}" );
}

sub wait_for_end {
   my $self = shift;
   my $timeout = shift;
   my $poll_interval = shift;

   # Is it even possible to pass the oject subroutine and retain the objects data?
   #unless ( $self->timeout( $timeout, $poll_interval, $self->get_flag_end ) ) { # does not work
   unless ( $self->timeout( $timeout, $poll_interval, \&get_flag_end ) ) {       # call happens but members are empty
      die "!!!ERROR!!! Timed out while waiting for wait_for_end: timeout=$timeout, poll_interval=$poll_interval \n";
   }
}

sub timeout {
   my $self = shift;
   my $timeout = shift;
   my $poll_interval = shift;
   my $test_condition = shift;
   until ($test_condition->() || $timeout <= 0) {
      $timeout -= $poll_interval;
      sleep $poll_interval;
   }
   return $timeout > 0; # condition was met before timeout
}
```

I know that I could change the "get_flag_end" routine to take the value as an argument to the subroutine but what if there was a bunch of stuff done in "get_flag_end" and I needed more members from the object. I simplified the code a bit to make it a little easier to follow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make a closure and pass that in:

```
sub wait_for_end {
   my $self = shift;
   my $timeout = shift;
   my $poll_interval = shift;

   my $callback = sub { $self->get_flag_end() };

   unless ( $self->timeout( $timeout, $poll_interval, $callback ) ) {
      die "!!!ERROR!!! Timed out while waiting for wait_for_end: timeout=$timeout, poll_interval=$poll_interval \n";
   }
}
```

**Update:**

The other option is, since `timeout` is a method of the same class, pass in a method name.

```
sub wait_for_end {
   my $self = shift;
   my $timeout = shift;
   my $poll_interval = shift;

   my $callback = sub { $self->get_flag_end() };

   unless ( $self->timeout( $timeout, $poll_interval, 'get_flag_end' ) ) {
      die "!!!ERROR!!! Timed out while waiting for wait_for_end: timeout=$timeout, poll_interval=$poll_interval \n";
   }
}

sub timeout {
  my $self = shift;
  my $timeout = shift;
  my $poll_interval = shift;
  my $method = shift;

  # Do whatever

  # Now call your method.
  $self->$method();

}
```

Comment: So if I wanted to learn more about this subject I could look at the docs for "closure"?

Comment: @stephenmm, Check out perlfaq7 "What's a closure?" http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq7.html#What's-a-closure%3f

Answer (score 2):

In your `$test_condition->()` line, you are calling the subroutine but not passing it any arguments.  Chances are what you meant was `$test_condition->($self)` or perhaps as `$self->$test_condition`

Here is a refactor of your code, correcting a few other issues:

```
sub get_flag_end {
   my $self = shift;
   return -e $self->{file}; # no need to quote the variable
}

sub wait_for_end {
   my ($self, $timeout, $poll_interval) = @_;  # unpack many args at once

   unless ( $self->timeout( $timeout, $poll_interval, $self->can('get_flag_end') ) ) {
      die "!!!ERROR!!! Timed out while waiting for wait_for_end: timeout=$timeout, poll_interval=$poll_interval \n";
   }
}

sub timeout {
   my ($self, $timeout, $poll_interval, $test_condition) = @_;
   until ($self->$test_condition || $timeout <= 0) {
      $timeout -= $poll_interval;
      sleep $poll_interval;
   }
   return $timeout > 0; # condition was met before timeout
}
```

Depending on the rest of your implementation, creating a subroutine that knows its invocant might be better.  You can do this in Perl with a closure:

```
unless ( $self->timeout( $timeout, $poll_interval, sub {$self->get_flag_end} )){
```

Here a new subroutine is created, which remembers the value of `$self`.  You would call it without arguments `$test_condition->()`